# How to reuse threads using pthread_exit()

Tags: c, pthreads

My computer allows 380 threads per process, which is fine for me. I have no problem 
when I call 380 times to function sdfpthread_create (). But successive call returns the 
erro 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable).

The apparent solution is to use the pthread_exit (), but I did not solve the problem, the 
limit is still 380 threads created.

How I can reuse thread?

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <pthread.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <unistd.h>


    void *doSomeThing()
    {
        sleep(99);
        pthread_exit(NULL);
    }

    int main(void)
    {
        pthread_t tid;
        int i;
        int err;

        /* Create threads */
        for (i=0; i<380; ++i)  {
            err = pthread_create(&tid, NULL, doSomeThing, NULL);
            if (err != 0)
                printf("\n1) Can't create thread :[%s]", strerror(err));
        }

        sleep(1);

        /* Reuse threads */
        for (i=0; i<5; ++i)  {
            err = pthread_create(&tid, NULL, doSomeThing, NULL);
            if (err != 0)
                printf("\n2) Can't create thread :[%s]", strerror(err));
        }

        exit(0);
    }
```

Comment: This isn't very clear.  Are you saying that the above code works, or not?

Answer (score 4):

You need to call [`pthread_join(3)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/pthread_join.3.html) to actually cleanup thread exit state, or create threads that are not joinable.

#### Edi 0:

Please see *and read*:

- [`pthread_create(3)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/pthread_create.3.html)
- [`pthread_detach(3)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/pthread_detach.3.html)
- [`pthread_attr_setdetachstate(3)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/pthread_attr_setdetachstate.3.html)

Comment: I used pthread_detach(pthread_self()); and I have no problem. Your help was very useful. Thanks.