# Reuse thread struct after thread_join in C

Tags: c, multithreading, stack, pthreads

I have an array of thread variables on the stack, which the main thread later joins with.  I have to run the same number of threads again later, and was wondering if I can still use the same array of thread structs to create new threads, or if the thread struct can't be used again to create new threads.

Something like this:

```
main_method() {

    pthread_t threads[10]
    for (all threads)
        pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, some_func, &arg[i])

    for (each thread in threads[10])
        pthread_join(&threads[i]), ...)

    // Does this work?
    for (each thread in threads[10])
        pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, other_func, &arg[i])

    //Or do I have to do this
    pthread_t threads2[10]

    for (each thread in threads2[10])
        pthread_create(&threads2[i], NULL, other_func, &arg[i])
```

Similar question asked here, but wasn't sure if the answer addressed the above question.

[How to reuse threads using pthread_exit()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14691439/how-to-reuse-threads-using-pthread-exit)

Comment: If you don't let them terminate, don't join and, instead, just loop back and block on some syncro, you can 're-use' the threads, (because they never terminate).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a thread exits, it's done.  You can't "reuse" it - create another one.  You can reuse your array of course - but not the values inside of it. (ie. need to pthread_create again)

The question you cite was asking about the maximum number of /concurrent/ threads - OP was not joining or having his threads exit. There's no limit on the number of threads you can use over the lifetime of a program execution.

Comment: So I can use the space in the array to create new threads?  I.e. the code under "does this work" will create new threads that will run "other_func"

Comment: Yes, @Marc Fraioli's "does this work" will work.  He also hints at the right way to think about the objects in your array - they are like "references" to the actual threads.  When the thread exits, think of the reference as dangling (it's not quite like that, but that's the right idea).  Your array stores some references, you're free to create new objects and overwrite the old references with new ones.

Comment: Thanks that really clears it up.   From what I understand  the thread struct 'references' a running thread, and we can reuse that space to store information for a new thread once we are sure that the original thread has exited (and we are sure no other threads will reference the struct thread's fields).

Answer (score 1):

You are asking two questions which are actually not equivalent. To directly answer the question in the comment of your code snippet:

```
// Does this work?
for (each thread in threads[10])
    pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, other_func, &arg[i])
```

The answer is yes, that works.

But it is not doing what the subject of your question asks-- it is not reusing any actual running threads. When you call `pthread_create()`, it both creates a thread and stores an identifier in the space pointed to by its first argument. So you are reusing that storage to store a new id, but you have created a brand new thread.

Comment: Awesome thanks, I'll edit the question to (hopefully) reflect that more clearly.